# Question #2: Finding the probability of a decline higher than 9%

Tags: finance

Expected monthly price change=E(x) = 0.60%
Average monthly volatility = 9.40%

I am looking for the probability that gold will decline by more than 9% in the next month.

According to the formula for z score: X - E(X) / σ the equation would be= 9%-0.60% / 9.40%

Which is = .8936 which on the z score table is .3133

Since Z is positive, the probability would be 0.5 - .3133 = 0.1867 meaning that the probability of gold declining by more than 9% would be 18.67% but this is not shown on the multiple select.

A. 15.39%
B. 85%
C. 10.22%
d. 22.36%

Comment: A decline of more than 9 percent is expressed via $P(X \leq -9 )$.

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment. 

How would that be expressed as a formula ?

-9%-o.60%/9.40% ?

Comment: From your usage of the transformation to standard normal distribution it's clear that you didn't understand it correctly. The price change of gold is the random variable $X$, which is normal (not standard normal) distributed. To calculate the wanted probability you need to transform $X$ to a standard normal distributed random variable $Z$ correctly. Than you can use a Z-table to just read of the probability, exactly as you did in your approach.

Comment: Thank you so much